# "undefined method `fixtures' for ActiveSupport::TestCase:Class" while testing with Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I'm writing tests for a Gem and after a couple of hours trying to get rid of this, decided to look around - and to my surprise, there's not a single reference to it on Google (apart from one on mongoid, where people simply ignored it).

So, the problem is simple: I have this block on my test initialization:

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  fixtures :all
end
```

but the tests fail to execute:

```
`<class:TestCase>': undefined method `fixtures' for ActiveSupport::TestCase:Class (NoMethodError)
```

The gem depends on Rails 3 and every dependency is checked & double-checked. The code is on github, in case anyone wants to check (https://github.com/herval/acts_as_recommendable)
I'm out of ideas. Anyone share a light?

Comment: did you ever figure out what was going on here?  I'm seeing similar behavior...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a long time since I used Rails' built in testing, so take this with a grain of salt.  I'm guessing that the actual ActiveSupport::TestCase class hasn't actually been loaded before the initializer is being reached.

It might be enough to just add `require 'test_help'` at the top of the initializer.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure, but it seems that fixtures cannot be used with mongoid.

Take a look at this for further details:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongoid/tqlx3j88Lqw

Comment: Is this also the case with RethinkDB?
I am using Rails 5.0.0.beta4 with nobrainer gem and get the same error message.