# undefined method `users' for Tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4, fixtures

I'm trying to write a simple test but my application is not detecting 'users' keyword when I'm using it in my Test functions:

`post_controller_test.rb`:

```
require 'test_helper'

class PostsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  # test "the truth" do
  #   assert true
  # end

  test "should fetch facebook post" do
    sign_in users(:one)
    get(:save_posts_from_facebook_page,{'id'=>'my_id'},{'access_token'=>Rails.application.secrets.fb_access_token})
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

`test_helper.rb`:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
    include Devise::TestHelpers
  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end
```

`users.yml`:

```
# Read about fixtures at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html

one:
  email: hello@testing.com
  encrypted_password: <%= Devise.bcrypt(User,'password') %>
  links: 
  causes: 

two:
  email: MyString
  password: MyString
  links: 
  causes:
```

Output of rake/Error:

```
Run options: --seed 42684

# Running:

E

Finished in 0.010275s, 97.3279 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
PostsControllerTest#test_should_fetch_facebook_post:
NoMethodError: undefined method `users' for #<PostsControllerTest:0x000001042152f0>
    test/controllers/posts_controller_test.rb:9:in `block in <class:PostsControllerTest>'

1 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

Update:
*Note that I'm using MongoId.*

When I add 'fixtures :all' to my test_helper.rb, I get:

rake

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `fixtures' for ActiveSupport::TestCase:Class
/Users/gautambajaj/My Stuff/FreeFromBorders/f2b_website/test/test_helper.rb:7:in `<class:TestCase>'
/Users/gautambajaj/My Stuff/FreeFromBorders/f2b_website/test/test_helper.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/gautambajaj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/Users/gautambajaj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/Users/gautambajaj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/Users/gautambajaj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/Users/gautambajaj/My Stuff/FreeFromBorders/f2b_website/test/controllers/posts_controller_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/gautambajaj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/Users/gautambajaj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/Users/gautambajaj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/Users/gautambajaj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/Users/gautambajaj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/Users/gautambajaj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `each'
/Users/gautambajaj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/Users/gautambajaj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:113:in `each'
/Users/gautambajaj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:113:in `block in define'
/Users/gautambajaj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:20:in `invoke_rake_task'
/Users/gautambajaj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake:8:in `block in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => test:run
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Mongodb doesn't have transactions, so transactional fixtures can't be used here. And fixtures without transactions are useless anyway. Use FactoryGirl or something like it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `test_helper.rb` file, you need to add `fixtures :all`:

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all
  # rest of the codes in this file
end
```

Once you add that line in your `test_helper.rb` file as shown above, your test will pass.

#### Update

As Sergio Tulentsev mentioned in the comment, Mongodb doesn't support transactions, so transactional fixtures can't be used in your case. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13713214/981183) which states that and also this [google group discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongoid/tqlx3j88Lqw) as well.

I would recommend you to use [factory_girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) instead, which supports mongoid and is pretty awesome.

Comment: I now get "NoMethodError: undefined method `fixtures' for ActiveSupport::TestCase:Class" Notice that, I'm using MongoId

Comment: I have updated my answer. Apparently, fixtures are not supported with mongoid. You have to use some alternative I think.

Comment: Spent around 30 minutes trying to figure out why users was undefined and this got it working. I wonder though why didn't they just add the line `fixtures :all` in there by default? After all I was just trying to run the default (generated) tests.